# Center footer PDF using SelectPdf .NET

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core

Hi i'm using SelectPdf for Net Core.

First i generate a method for convert html content to pdf, then i configure my pdf options and finally i add footer in all pages, this work but I can't find any property to center my footer in the document.

```
       public string _htmlStringToBase64(string htmlContent)
       {
          HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();

          converter.Options.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4;
          converter.Options.DisplayFooter = true;
          converter.Footer.DisplayOnFirstPage = true;
          converter.Footer.DisplayOnOddPages = true;
          converter.Footer.DisplayOnEvenPages = true;
          converter.Footer.Height = 80;

          converter.Options.MarginLeft = 20;
          converter.Options.MarginRight = 20;
          converter.Options.MarginBottom = 30;
          converter.Options.MarginTop = 15;

          //this footer options
          PdfHtmlSection footerHtml = new PdfHtmlSection(ExternalResources.FooterBase64Img);
          footerHtml.AutoFitHeight = HtmlToPdfPageFitMode.ShrinkOnly;
          footerHtml.CustomCSS = "text-align: center;";  //I tried that but it doesn't work
          converter.Footer.Add(footerHtml);

          var docPDF = converter.ConvertHtmlString(htmlContent);
          MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

          docPDF.Save(stream);
          docPDF.Close();

          return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray())
       }
```

As I said, the footer unfolds without problems but I need to center it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of the PdfHtmlSection class has several overloads, one of them allows the X, Y axes and the url of the image.
You can try assigning a value to the X axis which is the one that aligns horizontally, you can try the following code:

```
 PdfHtmlSection footerHtml = new PdfHtmlSection(100, 0,ExternalResources.FooterBase64Img);
```

where the 100 value is the position offset from left

the next url show all properties:  https://selectpdf.com/docs/Overload_SelectPdf_PdfHtmlSection__ctor.htm